# Transfer game to new account on PS5

Tags: ps4, grand-theft-auto-v, psn, ps5, rockstar-games-social-club

My son had a PS4 which I was playing GTA5 on. He transferred his account to his new PS5. Now both consoles are using one account, is it possible to create a new account on the PS4 and transfer GTA5 saved data onto the new account?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it by clicking the green tick

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that you want to transfer saved data from the old PS4 account to a newly created one, then no, that's not possible.

Saved data are bound to the account that created them and can't be moved to another.